# Tridion Upgrade 2009 to 2013

Tags: 2013, 2009, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade my Tridion 2009 to 2013. We have been using 2009 features as mentioned below. Initially it's  a AS-IS state upgrade. Please advise if any of the feature will require code changes and would appreciate if could provide details around this.  I am following Tridion Upgrade Documentation & Deprecation Guide.

- **Workflow**: Implemented  workflow using VBScript & .Net DLL. Have created TDSE object using VBScript, also using COM methods in VBScript for various workflow  activities. Please advise if Tridion 2013  supports the legacy VBScript workflow or  a code change to be  done?

  i.e. `Set oTDSE = CreateObject("TDS.TDSE")`
- **C# TBB**: C# Code   compiled in .Net framework 2.0.
- **DWTs Code** – CT/PTs: Standard 2009  DWT with no JScript/VBScript.
- **Component Linking**: Standard Component linking.
- **UI Extension**: Tridion Tool bar extension. Added custom button in RTF editor.
- **Custom resolver**: Used TOM.Net API Publishing engine object.
- **Custom Functions**: Common utility functions in shared DLL deployed at GAC.
- **Site Edit**: Standard 2009 DWT template code

  i.e; `<tcdl:ComponentField name="DetailContent[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Title">`
- **Broker**: Broker call  to fetch content.
- **Custom Pages**: Used TOM API for bulk publishing, search etc.
- **Security**: Standard 2009 implementation
- **Events**: No events

Here I am assuming, Tridion 2013 upgrade utility, upgrades the  CM & Broker Content and no changes are required to use it.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
~Vivek

Answer (score 4):

Your TBBs that rely on the TOM.NET API should be fine.  There are a few deprecated methods mostly around Filters, but they are only deprecated and should still work in Tridion 2013.

Your Custom DWT Function Sources should also be fine as they rely on TOM.NET.

Anything that relies on TOM/TDSE, including Workflow and Custom Pages will require a Legacy Pack installed for Tridion 2013.

Your UI extensions will need to be completely re-written, as a new framework has been introduced for this with Tridion 2011.

You will need to upgrade SiteEdit to Experience Manager, but any SiteEdit markup you used in a DWT template remains the same. In case you were using the SiteEdit TBBs, then you will need to replace them with the new XPM versions.

Comment: Adding to that, you will upgrade SiteEdit to Experience Manager, but any SiteEdit markup you used in a DWT template remains the same. In case you were using the SiteEdit TBBs, then you will need to replace them with the new XPM versions.

Comment: thanks for your response. 

Specific question on Workflow: 

 - Does  Legacy patch 100% assures that all functionalists will work? 
 - Also from where we can download Legacy patch? I could not find Legacy patch in my setup also there is no reference to Legacy patch in "SDL Tridion 2013 Installation Manual"

Comment: The Legacy Pack (not patch), is a separately purchased add-on, so you will need to speak to your Sales/Support contacts to get it.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I've added your SiteEdit comment into the answer.

Comment: @Nickoli I think you can install the legacy pack on a fresh install by running the standard 2013 installer with a command line flag (i forget what the flag is). Also I think I remember reading all upgrades will need the legacy pack IIRC. Will look for sources!

Answer (score 1):

We have recently upgraded from 5.3 to 2011, so i am writing based on my experience in that.

**C# TBB** - Update reference to 2011 Tridion Libraries such as Tridion.ContentManager.dll, common, Templating. after this you have to update filtering logic. its has been changed since 2011

```
filter.Conditions["ItemType"] = ItemType.StructureGroup;
```

**DWTs Code** - there should not be any issue with DWT

**SiteEdit** - Experience manager is different in installation & configuration. actually i used UI upgrade in our 2011,  there are lots of issue with that, like float left css property  is not supported in that. any CP css having that does not show border properly. so keep good time for this update.

**Broker Calls** - There are few changes you might have to do but depends on upon your current implementation. if possible do not upgrade exiting broker, do fresh publishing.